# How do I get Question 123388 reopened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[How do I get this question re-opened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123388/how-do-i-remove-lubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu-12-04)

A moderator has closed this question citing it as an exact duplicate, but its clear that any of the answers on the original question do not specifically answer the question I asked.

I have updated the question with an answer as the method I took to resolve is issue was not prescribed in another answer and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you update your question (you should be able to edit it, even though it's closed) to add more details to what you've tried, what isn't working, etc. From first glance it would appear that the closure was correct (though it should, in my opinion be a duplicate of [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop) ).

So while I agree with the current closure, it might be that those instructions are out of date, etc. Could you update your question with the exact steps you've tried, what questions you've viewed, any errors, or other information that would help us to narrow down the actual problem and provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am only starting to get accustomed how this AU site works.  I totally understand why you marked  my question a duplicate in the context you did.  But someone like me who is relatively new to this whole process uses the link and sees there are disputes with senior members about the accepted answer, well Im just going to be sceptical aren't I.  FYI, I eventually was able resolve my question using "Synaptic Package Manager".  Keep up the great work, AU is a terrific resource and this has been a lesson learned for me.

Comment: @StephenMyall If you eventually used a different method, that might be beneficial to others consider leaving it as an answer on the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. **Edit** your question to specify that your problem is different, and why. Note that "no answers from that other one work for me" is not an excuse.
2. **Check if any of the answers there work**
3. **Upvote** that question
4. **Comment** on the accepted answer that it does not work for your case; but don't spam it around. (if any answer works, don't do it, please)

Comment: This is a general answer, it does not intend to help the OP after a long time.